# using variables as values for height and width

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to use variables to set the height and width of an image but on what I tried, it's not functioning

// A = the image is chosen by using a dropdown list so i equated it on a variable to get the imagesize

// B = as you can see I enclosed $width & $height on a php argument since calling it directly did not work too. *This statement is to append the chosen image into the canvas I created.*

```
$imageX   = $('#imgChoose').val(); 

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageX);//A 

if( $imageX.length > 0){
    $(".image1a").append('<li><img src="JQS_Script/Images/Upload/' + $imageX + '" id="" width="<?php echo"$width";?>" height="<?php echo"$height";?>" /></li>');//B
```

```
<img src="JQS_Script/Images/Upload/' + $imageX + '" id="" width="<?php echo"$width";?>" height="<?php echo"$height";?>" />
```

//it was working, but when I equated width and height values into variables[$height,$width] it won't append/work anymore.

i hope i stated it clearly.

Comment: I'm seeing javascript and php mixed together? You can't use a jquery function `$('#imgChoose').val();` to assign to a php variable `$imageX`.

Comment: Correct.  PHP runs on the server, but JavaScript runs on the client, so you can run any server-side code with it.  If you explain what you're trying to do and why then we can advise you better :)

Comment: $imageX   = $('#imgChoose').val(); is javascript code, non PHP code. (It is perfectly legal, albeit a bit weird, to start Javascript variables with $)

Comment: So is `list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageX);`, but I am guessing the OP thought that last one would be interpreted as PHP (getimagesize being a PHP function)

Comment: i did mix javascript and php, which is part my fault, I'll try to write all of it in just php. thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed PHP and Javascript into the same script.

Don't forget, that once PHP has output it's generated content to the browser, it's execution has completed and no longer has the ability to mutate variables and execute code within your script.

In the following updated example, I'm assuming that getimagesize($imageX) is a javascript function? If not you'll also have to write that into JS.

```
$imageX   = $('#imgChoose').val(); 

var imgSizes = getimagesize($imageX);//A 

if( $imageX.length > 0){
    $(".image1a").append('<li><img src="JQS_Script/Images/Upload/' + $imageX + '" id="" width="<?php echo"+imgSizes[1]+";?>" height="'+imgSizes[1]+'" /></li>');//B
```

You can see that instead of using PHP's list() function, I'm just using the array directly to build the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the image at its original size, why not just omit the width and height declarations from the `<img>` tag?

Comment: I think `getimagesize()` is a php function, Paul.

Comment: I did that but the 'em' value would be 0 because the condition I used, uses the stated width and height of the image chosen. that means, the image will no be displayed literally, but logically it would be width=0 height=0